# How to add a virtual column by using PHQL

Tags: php, phalcon

How can I add virtual column by using models query object.This one doesn`t work

```
$user = User::query()
  ->columns(array(
    '*',
    '(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user`) AS `UserCnt`'
  ))
  ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use count like this:

```
// How many cars are by each brand?
$phql = "SELECT Cars.brand_id, COUNT(*) FROM Cars GROUP BY Cars.brand_id";
$rows = $manager->executeQuery($phql);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row->brand_id, ' ', $row["1"], "\n";
}
```

or with models abstraction:

```
$count = User::count();
```

or with filters:

```
$count = User::count("status= 'active'");
```